# What are the parameters in slim.conv3d?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

This is code for a layer in 3D CNN where my input is video frames. I am having difficulty in understanding what the parameters mean.

```
net = slim.conv3d(net, 64, [1, 3, 3], scope='conv32')

net = PReLU(net, 'conv32_activation')

net = tf.nn.max_pool3d(net, strides=[1, 1, 2, 2, 1], ksize=[1, 1, 3, 3, 1], padding='VALID', name='pool3')
```

Does [1,3,3] refer to my filter size?
and what are the 5 numbers in ksize?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Here you are using Conv3D, 
There are a lot of parameters, you can see them [here conv3d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/conv3d) and [maxpool3d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/max_pool3d).

Yes, [1,3,3] refers to your filter size.
ksize is the size of the window, essentially the dimensions that you want to consider while using maxpool.

[Here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) is an awesome guide to CNN with all things explained.